# Returning a formatted string does not working properly

Tags: java, format, return, duplicates, string.format

I have created a dupe-check that makes sure that newly created usernames are unique.

It looks like this:

```
String p1 = <code>; //First 3 chars in first name
String p2 = <code>; //First 3 chars in last name
int p3 = 1;         //Unique identifier.
boolean dupeCheck;

do {
  dupeCheck = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < userNameList.size(); i++) {
    if (userNameList.get(i).equals(p1+p2+Integer.toString(p3))) {
      dupeCheck = true;
      p3++;
    }
  }
} while (dupeCheck == true);
```

This works, if i return:

```
return String.format("%s%s%d", p1, p2, p3);
```

Duplicate usernames get names like:

- xxxyyy1
- xxxyyy2
- xxxyyy3

Which is great. But i want the unique identifier (`p3`) to allways be three digits long. This is where String.format comes into play, along with my problems.

If i return the following code:

```
return String.format("%s%s%03d", p1, p2, p3);
```

For some reason, the dupe check fails and i get these usernames:

- xxxyyy001
- xxxyyy001
- xxxyyy001

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: you format your username with leading 0. so your name is xxxyyy001, but you compare it with xxxyyy1. so your eqals will never return true. ... call your equals method with 'String.format("%s%s%03d", p1, p2, p3)'

Comment: did you check if p3 is increasing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you store usernames using %03d, i.e. with leading zeros, you also should use this when you compare the string in your userNameList:

```
userNameList.get(i).equals(String.format("%s%s%03d", p1, p2, p3))
```

Comment: That was the case! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

like said in the comment: you store your name not the same way you compare it.
you could also change your method this way:

```
    String p1 = "xxx"; //First 3 chars in first name
    String p2 = "yyy"; //First 3 chars in last name
    int p3 = 1;         //Unique identifier.


    while(true){ 
        if(userNamesList.contains(String.format("%s%s%03d", p1, p2, p3))){
            p3++;
        }
        else{
            return String.format("%s%s%03d", p1, p2, p3);
        }       
    }
```